# how to deploy to fabric8 using the spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, maven-3, spring-boot, fabric8

I started with the archetype io.fabric8:camel-cxf-code-first-archetype, but I wasn't able to deploy with the following maven command because there was no fabric8 defined.
mvn -P!spring-boot clean compile -X fabric8:deploy -DskipTests=true -Dfabric8.upload=true -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://10.191.231.12:8181/jolokia

I then modified my pom.xml to contain the following:

I am simply looking for any example that I can deploy to a fabric8 instance.  I have spent three days on this with no luck.
    
        
            spring-boot
            
                true
            
            
                
                    
                        org.springframework.boot
                        spring-boot-maven-plugin
                        
                        io.fabric8.process.spring.boot.container.FabricSpringApplication
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                    repackage

and

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Beta4</version>
        <configuration>
            <profile>com.aecom.sf-ebs-po</profile>
            <features>mq-fabric spring camel-cxf cxf-jaxrs camel-jackson camel-amq camel-jms camel-spring spring-jms process-manager csf-core</features>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Thanks,
Steve MunLeeuw

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using fabric8 v2 when using spring-boot as its rearchitectured around kubernetes and docker.

You can read about the v1 -> v2 changes here:
http://fabric8.io/v2/v2-changes.html

And then read the general v2 documentation and how to get started

The quickstarts are now in a separate github project, and the spring-boot quickstarts are here
https://github.com/fabric8io/quickstarts/tree/master/quickstarts/spring-boot

But they are also runnable out of the box if you use the web console, there is an app page where you can find all of them to easily run.

fabric8 v1 for spring-boot or java containers etc was an experiment, but then docker came along and changed the world, so we re-arhitected to v2. The current v1 is now focused to be only about OSGi for Karaf and JBoss Fuse. The upcoming JBoss Fuse 6.2 comes with fabric8 v1, but its intended to be the last v1 release, and newer releases of JBoss Fuse is being moved to fabric8 v2.

In other words move to v2

Comment: Claus, is there any preliminary time-frame for fabric8 v2 in Fuse?

Comment: There is the Fuse Integration Services product: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/xpaas_images/fuse.html

Comment: For JBoss Fuse product then 6.x is using fabric8 v1. I expect Fuse 7.0 to be where they upgrade. But its a company decision what they put in what products. As an engineer I have little to say.